# Python pySerial - Problem using subclasses

Tags: python, serialization, serial-port, subclass, pyserial

I'm working on a project in Python that uses two or more serial ports to manage some devices from my RPi. When ports are open in the same file and I send commands to different instances of serial.Serial object everything works fine. This is an example:

```
import serial

device1_port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
device2_port = "/dev/ttyUSB1"

# Command sent to device 1. No problem
d1 = serial.Serial(device1_port, timeout = 0.5)
d1.write(b'GET MUTE\n')
output1 = d1.readline()
print("Device 1 output: " + str(output1))


# Command sent to device 2. No problem
d2 = serial.Serial(device2_port, timeout = 1)
d2.write(b'00vP\r')
output2 = d2.readline()
print("Device 2 output: " + str(output2))
```

Output:

```
Device 1 output: b'DATA MUTE OFF\r\n'
Device 2 output: b'00vP0\r'
```

The problem comes when I try to separate one device from another using subclasses of serial.Serial. The reason is I want to deal with them like objects with their own methods (each device needs a lot of different commands, status queries...).

```
class device1(serial.Serial):
    def __init__(self, port, timeout):
        super().__init__(port, timeout)
        serial.Serial(port, timeout)

    def command1(self):
        self.write(b'SET MUTE OFF\n')
        self.write(b'GET MUTE\n')
        output = self.readline()
        print("Device 1 output: " + str(output))


class device2(serial.Serial):
    def __init__(self, port, timeout):
        super().__init__(port, timeout)
        serial.Serial(port, timeout)

    def command2(self):
        self.write(b'00vP\r')
        output = self.readline()
        print("Device 2 output: " + str(output))

device1_port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
device2_port = "/dev/ttyUSB1"

d1 = device1(device1_port, timeout=0.5)
d2 = device2(device2_port, timeout=1)

d1.command1()
d2.command2()
```

When I run this code the output is:

```
Device 1 output: b'DATA MUTE OFF\r\n'
_
```

and it keeps waiting forever for the second device. I'm forced to Ctrl + C and I get this:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ct3.py", line 35, in <module>
    d2.command2()
  File "./ct3.py", line 23, in command2
    output = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 483, in read
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.fd, self.pipe_abort_read_r], [], [], timeout.time_left())
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It's seems like there is some kind of conflict between the two subclasses but, obviously I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I have no clue at the moment, but add a print statement at the beginning of the functions `d1.command1()` and `d2.command2()` in order to see if command1 is blocking or if you enter `command2` and then you are stuck.

Comment: I did it and I can see that it hangs when reading serial port in second command. Finally found solution in the other answer. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `serial.Serial(port, timeout)` from your `__init__`,
as `super().__init__(...)` is already doing this. See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/5008284). You don't even need an `__init__` if you are not going to change what the base class does.

Also, there is a difference in your two versions with respect to the use of positional and keyword arguments. `serial.Serial()`'s first 2 positional arguments are `port, baudrate`, so you need to explicitly use the keyword argument `timeout=`:

```python
def __init__(self, port, timeout):
    super().__init__(port, timeout=timeout)
```

Comment: OK, I understand this. I remove `serial.Serial(port, timeout)` and keep `super().__init__(port, timeout)` but the result is the same :(

Comment: I see the other reason your classes differ. See my updated answer.

Comment: As you say, I didn't use _timeout_ as keyword argument. You saved my life! Thank you so much!